# Stop H2 database programmatically

Tags: java, database, tomcat, h2

Consider we have a `H2` database which is started from a web-application under `Tomcat` using `Hibernate`. In other words **it is an embedded `H2` database into the application**.

The question: is it possible to programmatically stop this `H2` server from this application and then start it again?

P.S. `Server.createTcpServer(args).start();` or `Server.shutdown(...)` is not the way, because it is in the embedded mode.

Comment: Do you use embedded H2 in the application? In that case, there is no H2 server running. Is your web-app the client of the H2 app? Is it the one embedding the app? What's your use case BTW? Why restart?

Comment: @DavidBrossard Let me do not explain why I need restart. Just help me please to do that :)

Comment: Fair enough :-) Still, if your db is embedded inside your app, what does restart mean then? Restart all jdbc connections to the db?

Comment: No, I mean actually `stop` database. That means, that h2 will not use its files on the disk while be shutdowned.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In this particular case such an approach will be a workable solution:

1. To stop H2 database just use `SHUTDOWN` sql command:

   `session.createSQLQuery("SHUTDOWN").executeUpdate();`
2. To restart H2 you don't need to do anything: the Tomcat's connection pool will do it automatically.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated!